# MacPorts: warning and failure of port installation

Tags: high-sierra, install, macports

Trying to install via MacPorts the recent Inkscape port update to @1.1.2 failed on High Sierra. Tracing the installation with `sudo port -t install inkscape` results in warnings

```
--->  Building inkscape
Warning: The following existing file was hidden from the build system by trace mode:
  /opt/local/include/boost
Warning: The following files inside the MacPorts prefix not installed by a port were accessed:
  /opt/local/include/boost/algorithm/string.hpp
  ...
  /opt/local/include/libxml2/unicode/uversion.h
Error: Failed to build inkscape: command execution failed
```

What is the meaning of these warnings and how can I get rid of?

Comment: As https://ports.macports.org/port/inkscape/details/ shows it builds so I would expect you to download a built version - so there is something non standard in your setup. What version of macport, whay is you default config what variant or inkscape are you building? Have you updated macports recently.

Comment: I am not sure whether something is not standard in my setup and I have no glue to figure this out. I use macport 2.7.1 and I tried the +x11 variant of Inkscape. I use the default macport config (nothing changed). I can update macport recently, other ports are working. Thus, it must be related to port Inkscape - I guess.

Comment: Ah I think the default is +quartz so that explains not getting the builf. I would run `self port selfupdate` and see what it says

Comment: I uninstalled the previous Inkscape @0.92 version. `sudo port self` gives no outdated ports. `sudo port install inkscape` tries the +x11 variant `inkscape-1.1.2_0+x11.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2`. However, checking the log file I found 2 error messages for a call to `insan` like
 info:build /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_graphics_inkscape/inkscape/work/inkscape-1.1.2/src/display/cairo-utils.cpp:775:20: error: no matching function for call to 'isnan'

But I can also try to use the +quartz variant.

Comment: Yes, +quartz variant is also not working (as expected).

Comment: Not as expected the central buildbots built it yesterday. and its port file was changed yesterday according to https://build.macports.org/builders/ports-10.13_x86_64-watcher/builds/46583

Comment: I suggewst you provide the full main.log and report as a bug to trac.macports.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to a mismatch of a **clang** and **Xcode** version `inkscape` failed to build finally.

Solution:
First reinstall **CommandLineTools** with `xcode-select --install` then adjust **clang** with `xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

Install `inkscape @1.1.2` via `sudo port install inkscape`. (Both variants `+x11` and `+quartz` are working).